# HQL Metadata equivalent to oracle or any DB

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g

I am looking for getting the hibernate metadata from the entity class,which is equivalent to Oracle or any DB.
Example :
When we create metadata like :

```
ClassMetadata metadata = getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Cat.class);
```

and then try to get the propertyname and propertyType by:

```
for(String propertyName:propertyArry){
                System.out.print(propertyName);
                System.out.print("\t");
                Type type = metadata.getPropertyType(propertyName);
                metadata.
                System.out.print(type);
                System.out.println();
            }
```

We will get the hibernate property name and the type. But I want to display data type and data name from the table. Say,
if my hibernate property is typeId and equivalent property in DB is TYPE_ID ,in the same way type of the property typeId is Long ,but in DB its NUMBER. How to retrieve the data_type and property name of the Table from AbstractEntityPersister? not the entity property name and the type.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Do you want to know the data types of table columns?

Comment: @Beege I need both data types and data names of the table column